# Java Basic Audio Effects and Crop on OGG Vorbis

Tags: java, audio, oggvorbis, audioeffect

I'm working on a project in Java where I need to take an OGG Vorbis sound file of unknown length, and crop it into individual 1-second segments, then apply a fade out effect to all of those segments as well as a fade in to the first segment. Then these segments need to all be saved as individual files.

I've been looking around at the Java SPI and such, and got it to decode and open an OGG, but I couldn't get it to properly apply the effects on the segments or save them to files.

A friend suggested I try using OpenIMAJ (http://openimaj.org/), and it looks like it probably has what I need, but I can't find a good tutorial on it.

How can I load an OGG file programmatically through Java and apply audio effects to 1-second segments, then save those 1-second segments individually?